# Apache Tomcat - Access Files Outside Webroot

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, io, web

I had deployed an application in the application server Apache 
Tomcat. My GWT application needs to access files in folder "C: 
\Storage". In development mode the application runs like a charm but 
in an external web server (Apache Tomcat) it does not run, crashes 
when it tries to copy files from "C:\Storage" to "\docs". I think this 
might be because i'm trying to access files outside the webroot. How 
can i solve this situation? Using apache commons libs to deal with 
files? Could be permissions? I need some enlightment, some help will 
be very apreciated. 
Thanks in advance,

João Cavaleiro.

Comment: `it does not run, crashes when it tries to copy files..` - please provide exceptions that you see `catalina.out` or any other relevant log file that you might have.

Comment: You must provide more details, e.g. an exception stack trace. What exactly is `\docs` and how does it relate to `C:\storage`? Your production environment is hopefully not Linux?

Comment: maybe you should look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579224/setting-catalina-policy-to-allow-file-access-by-servlets

Answer (score 0):

Another (wild) guess: if you deploy wars without unpacking as real files, getRealPath("/doc") will return null. (You have no files inside a war). So you have to configure Tomcat:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html

```
upackWAR = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for the replies. I actually figured out what the problem was: Paths.

"\docs" is the folder located in the root of the app.

Unfortunately Apache didn't wrote any exception on catalina.out log (the code catch the exceptions ocurred).

Simply i didn't create a new File(pathname) with the absolute path of the destination location, i was using only the "docs/filename.txt" assuming that the File classe would recognize the full path, "knowing" the location in the filesystem of the app. I assume that this is a situation to keep in mind with sepecific application servers because with eclipse/Jetty it works but with Apache Tomcat don't (I am developing a GWT application).

But in the matteer of fact, the debbug was not easy, the debbug mode with external server didn't work in the server side in the peace of code where i it's needed to do this io operations strange), and the System.out.println that i managed to help me figure out the problem didn't show up in the catalina.stdout (strange to and yes, i have compiled and deployed it on the Apache Tomcat with that modifications twice).

Thanks to everyone.