# Unable to rename File using File#renameTo() method

Tags: java, file, tomcat, java-io

I want to move file from one folder to other. I am using `File#renameTo()` method, but file is not renamed. I am not getting what is going wrong.

I am using Netbeans 7.0.1 and Apache Tomcat.

Comment: the important part of the exception is missing, it starts somewhere in the middle

Comment: I agree with oers, the stack trace you posted doesn't show the cause of the Exception.... but I bet you're having permission problems....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are trying to move files around in a web application.

**Remember : servlets running in containers are restricted in terms of where they can read/write files - this is a security measure that is configurable .**

You have several options :

1) Use a simpler servlet container like Jetty (the security defaults in Jetty are less restrictive).

2) Update the catalina policies file : [Setting catalina.policy to allow file access by servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579224/setting-catalina-policy-to-allow-file-access-by-servlets)

3) Be more careful about where your trying to move files to.  The servlet API has "getResource..." hooks which reference you to the servlets "home" environment.

You might also take this as a precaution : I find that when I'm moving things around at the file level in a servlet, its usually due to a shortcut which is unnecessary (take a good look at existing Java EE APIs, are you sure that the functionality youre getting out of all this File I/O isn't already provided ...?) ...

Comment: i am trying to move the files using jsp files. i am not using servlets. i am student sir. can u suggest something simple

Comment: i am unable  load full stack trace because i am using this site for first time , and when i try upload it it gives some indentation error

Comment: The simplest thing I can suggest is to run your application in jetty (from your perspective, jetty the same as tomcat : http://www.enavigo.com/2008/08/29/deploying-a-web-application-to-jetty/).  That might fix it because the default permissions are more relaxed.

Answer (score 1):

whatever the files you want to rename, keep those files inside your application, then permission problem won't come.if you keep outside your application, there are chances to getting permission problem.