# Tomcat file access restriction/allowance per IP

Tags: java, tomcat, restriction, file-security

Is there a way to restrict/allow access to a specific file on Tomcat only to certain IPs? If there is no direct way to do this, what would be a good workaround?

I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: This answer might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579224/setting-catalina-policy-to-allow-file-access-by-servlets

Answer (score 0):

Use a [filter](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-writing-filters.htm) and get the ip from the [request](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html). However in case the request comes from behind a firewall, you'll get the firewall's ip.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do so with Tomcat ;)

Code:

```
<Context path="/here is youre path to the files">
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
             allow="here u put the IP addresses you want to allow" deny="here u put the IP addresses you want to deny"/>
    </Context>
```

I highly recommend you to read the Tomcat Tips which have been published by O´reilly. Can be found [here](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html?page=2).

Number 10 on there Site is about your Question

EDIT: This has to be pasted to your Server.xml

EDIT1: OTHER Way can be found here [Tomcat Valve settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839618/tomcat-valve-settings)

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do it, depending on exactly what you want to do.  For example:

- [Remote IP Valves](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve).
- [Remote Address Filters](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter)
- [Remote Host Filters](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Host_Filter)

Or if you wanted something fine-grained (e.g. pattern matching on the path part of the request URL) then you could implement your own Filter class.